How to format a random effect (i.e., + 0 vs. + 1) in my glmmTMB models
I am working on creating GLMMs to determine the effect of in-air noise on harbor seals. I have a couple other fixed predictor variables (current velocity and time) and some random effects. As I am fresh out of undergrad, I have taken only one basic stats/R class and am thus very new to modeling. I am struggling to format my random effect variables in my models. I have used ChatGPT and Google to try and figure out how best to format them but am still not confident I am doing it correctly.
To further complicate things I believe I need to account for temporal autocorrelation as I measured the same seals (presumably) over the year of data collection. To do that I plan on using either ar1() or ou() covariance structures. I asked a question about which of those to use in this post (ar1() or ou() for my glmmTMB models in RStudio?).
In the vignette on covariance structure the basic structure to either ar1() or ou() is
ar1(times + 0 | group). I am a bit confused on which of my variables should be “times” and which be “group.” I had someone explain it to me that times would be “month” in my case because it is specifying the within group (observation ID in my model) correlation structure. I do not fully understand that explanation and wanted to get others’ thoughts on this. Currently, in my data month is a factor variable that contains 13 levels, and there are multiple data points within each level. Observation ID is also a factor and is a unique number for each data point, with a total of 134 levels/data points.
Also in this vignette is a link to an explanation of the + 0 term (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html#construction-of-structured-covariance-matrices). I read through the whole webpage but am still unsure whether I should use + 0, +1, or -1 for my model. The same person who gave me the above advice said to use -1 (because of the time lag in my ACF plot), but so far my code has not been working well with that structure.
All of this is to provide background on my question of how do I structure the random effect/autocorrelation part of my model?
A similar post to mine that is unanswered is linked here: Fitting a negative binomial model and covariance structure syntax in glmmTMB.
Here is how I currently have my fitted model coded:
fittedModel<- glmmTMB(count ~ avgnoise + PC1 + time +
                      ar1(observ_id - 1 | month), data = full_data, 
                      family = nbinom2(link="log"))

